# Axiomatic Independence and Truth

Tags: logic, axioms

So let the sentence $s$ be independent from an axiomatic system $A$ (like PA or ZFC), i.e. neither $s$ nor $\lnot s$ is provable there. Now I read that $s$ is true in case $s$ = $\forall x Px$ and $s$ is false in case $s$ = $\exists x Px$.

1. My understanding is this: If for example $s$ = $\forall x Px$ and it's independent from $A$ then the truth of $s$ hangs in the air. Our only way is to go to a more powerful (and sound) system than $A$ - let's call it $A'$ - and prove there that indeed there is no x in the domain that fulfills $\lnot P$, so basically one proves $s$ in $A'$ and since $A'$ is sound $s$ is true and that means $s$ was already true in $A$ but there we couldn't prove it due to $A$'s limitations. So far so good, but $A'$ could also prove $s$ false, by proving that there's indeed some object $o$ with $\lnot P(o)$ which was overseen by $A$, couldn't it? So that would make it false to say with my book that if $s$ is independant from some $A$ but has the form $\forall x Px$ it must be true, right? It depends. Am I correct or my book?
2. If what I read in the book was true one could basically make an axiom that says: if a statement and its negation is not provable with the usual tools (axioms, theorems via inference rules), but has the form "$\forall x Px$", it's considered to be proven, else the negation is proved. Then Goedel's incompleteness would not be a problem anymore, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

*There are multiple questions on this site already about independence implying truth/falsity for appropriate formulas/systems; however, as far as I can tell this is not an exact duplicate, primarily due to the idea behind (1) in the OP.*

---

Let's work in PA (= first-order Peano arithmetic) for simplicity.

You haven't precisely stated the relevant principle: what is true, **and PA proves this**, is the following:

> If $s$ has the form $\exists xP(x)$ for a "simple" formula $P$ and $s$ is independent of PA, then $s$ is false.
>
> If $s$ has the form $\forall xP(x)$ for a "simple" formula $P$ and $s$ is independent of $PA$, then $s$ is true.

Here "simple" has a technical meaning, namely **using only bounded quantifiers**. More snappily, using the jargon of the arithmetical hierarchy we have:

> Every $\Sigma^0_1$ sentence independent of PA is false, and every $\Pi^0_1$ sentence independent of PA is true.

And to reiterate, **the above statement is provable in PA**. The simplicity requirement here is crucial: in general, we can't deduce $s$ or $\neg s$ from PA + "$s$ is independent of PA."

---

So why is that true?

Well, it's much easier to think about when rephrased as follows:

> PA proves every true $\Sigma^0_1$ sentence.

That is, PA is **$\Sigma^0_1$-complete**. The idea is that a $\Sigma^0_1$-sentence is true iff there is some natural number serving as a "witness" to it in a way which can be checked by basic calculations; every natural number is given by a term in PA, so PA can produce a "guess-and-check" proof of any specific true $\Sigma^0_1$-sentence. (For the fact that PA proves that PA is $\Sigma^0_1$-complete, see the discussion [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/258431/who-first-proved-that-we-can-prove-that-we-prove-things-we-prove).)

The $\Sigma^0_1$-completeness of PA immediately proves the above "truth/falsity-from-independence" results:

- If $s$ is $\Sigma^0_1$ and PA-unprovable, then since PA is $\Sigma^0_1$-complete $s$ must be false.
- If $s$ is $\Pi^0_1$ and PA-un-disprovable, then just think about $\neg s$.

Hopefully this demystifies the situation.

At this point I ought to address your point (1). I think the issue comes down to the requirement that the new system $A'$ be sound: we can't have one sound system decide a sentence one way and another sound system decide it a different way! Soundness means not proving any false statements, so two sound systems can never disagree - although of course one might prove something the other can't. So the "divergent sound extensions" phenomenon you're describing can't actually happen.

---

Now what about your point (2)?

Well, the issue is that **someone still needs to prove** the relevant independence fact! For example, the Godel sentence $G_{PA}$ is $\Pi^0_1$, hence true if PA-independent. Moreover, PA proves that - that is, PA proves "If $G_{PA}$ is PA-independent, then $G_{PA}$." However, PA *doesn't* quite prove "$G_{PA}$ is PA-independent." All PA can do is prove "**If PA is consistent** then $G_{PA}$ is PA-independent," but that's not quite enough.

So we're stuck with the same issue as always: **what system are we using to prove things in?** Once we fix an appropriate system $T$ (say, PA), there will be relevant independence phenomena which $T$ can't prove. In particular, $T$ won't be able to prove **any** independence phenomenon over itself (if it did, it would prove its own consistency: nothing is independent over an inconsistent theory!).

Comment: 1. Just to clarify: The original Goedel sentence isn't such a "simple" formula, so that he'd need a stronger system than PA (PA+Semantics or ZFC) to be proven true, right? 2. In math truth is - as in normal sciences - independent from proof systems. So it means for a mathematician there is some truth that one and one adds up to two even 500.000 years ago where neither numbers not PA existed? In this case math couldn't reach certainty (even with sound and complete proof systems) because of this gap: since the proof system doesn't match truth you can never be sure if truth is proved.